# MPAndroidChart - How to set data in BarChart using MPAndroidChart library from firebase Realtime Database using ValueEventListener?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, bar-chart, mpandroidchart

I am trying to set data in `BarChart` from firebase using `ValuEventListener`.
But when I am trying to set data in `BarEntry` ArrayList then the activity is crashing.
I used here **MPAndroidChart** library. I want to set data as an ArrayList in Barchart.

**Here my java code**

```
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarChart;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.BarData;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.BarDataSet;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.BarEntry;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.interfaces.datasets.IBarDataSet;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.utils.ColorTemplate;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.leo.simplearcloader.SimpleArcLoader;

import org.eazegraph.lib.models.BarModel;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class FindDataByAge extends AppCompatActivity implements ValueEventListener {


    BarChart barChart;

    FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference();
    DatabaseReference oneTo10 = databaseReference.child("1-10");
    DatabaseReference elevenTo20 = databaseReference.child("11-20");
    DatabaseReference twenty1To30 = databaseReference.child("21-30");
    DatabaseReference thirty1To40 = databaseReference.child("31-40");
    DatabaseReference forty1to50 = databaseReference.child("41-50");
    DatabaseReference fiftyTo60 = databaseReference.child("51-60");
    DatabaseReference sixty1Plus = databaseReference.child("61+");
    String elevenTo20String, stringOneTo10, stringTwenty1To30, stringThirty1To40, string41T050, string51T060, string61;
    SimpleArcLoader simpleArcLoader;
    TextView tvOneTo10, tvElevenTo20, tvLastUpdate, tvTwenty1To30, tvThirty1To40, tvForty1to50, tvFiftyTo60, tvSixty1Plus;

    LinearLayout linearLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_find_data_by_age);

        barChart = findViewById(R.id.barchartM);

        barChart.setDrawBarShadow(false);
        barChart.setDrawValueAboveBar(true);
        barChart.setMaxVisibleValueCount(50);
        barChart.setPinchZoom(false);
        barChart.setDrawGridBackground(false);

        ArrayList<BarEntry> barEntries = new ArrayList<>();
        barEntries.add(new BarEntry("1-10",Float.parseFloat(stringOneTo10)));
        barEntries.add(new BarEntry("11-20", Float.parseFloat(stringElevenTo20)));
        barEntries.add(new BarEntry("21-30", Float.parseFloat(stringTwenty1To30)));
        barEntries.add(new BarEntry("31-40", Float.parseFloat(stringThirty1To40)));
        barEntries.add(new BarEntry("41-50", Float.parseFloat(string41T050)));
        barEntries.add(new BarEntry("51-60", Float.parseFloat(string51T060)));
        barEntries.add(new BarEntry("61+", Float.parseFloat(string61)));

        BarDataSet barDataSet=new BarDataSet(barEntries,"Data set 1");

        BarData barData=new BarData();
        barData.addDataSet(barDataSet);
        barChart.setData(barData);
        barChart.setBackgroundColor(0xFF343456);
        barChart.setBorderColor(0xFF873F56);
        barDataSet.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);
        barChart.invalidate();




        linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.scrollAge);
        simpleArcLoader = findViewById(R.id.loaderAge);

        tvOneTo10 = findViewById(R.id.oneTo10);
        tvElevenTo20 = findViewById(R.id.elevenTo20);
        tvTwenty1To30 = findViewById(R.id.twentyOneTo30);
        tvThirty1To40 = findViewById(R.id.thirty1To40);
        tvForty1to50 = findViewById(R.id.fortyOneTo50);
        tvFiftyTo60 = findViewById(R.id.fiftyOneTo60);
        tvSixty1Plus = findViewById(R.id.sixtyOne);


    }



    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        if (dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class) != null) {


            simpleArcLoader.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            simpleArcLoader.start();


            String key = dataSnapshot.getKey();
            if (key.equals("1-10")) {

                stringOneTo10 = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                tvOneTo10.setText(stringOneTo10);


            }
            if (key.equals("11-20")) {

                stringElevenTo20= dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                tvElevenTo20.setText(stringElevenTo20);


            }
            if (key.equals("21-30")) {

                stringTwenty1To30 = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                tvTwenty1To30.setText(stringTwenty1To30);


            }
            if (key.equals("31-40")) {

                stringThirty1To40 = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                tvThirty1To40.setText(stringThirty1To40);


            }
            if (key.equals("41-50")) {

                string41T050 = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                tvForty1to50.setText(string41T050);


            }
            if (key.equals("51-60")) {

                string51T060 = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                tvFiftyTo60.setText(string51T060);


            }

            if (key.equals("61+")) {

                string61 = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                tvSixty1Plus.setText(string61);


            }

            simpleArcLoader.stop();
            simpleArcLoader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            linearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        oneTo10.addValueEventListener(this);
        elevenTo20.addValueEventListener(this);
        twenty1To30.addValueEventListener(this);
        thirty1To40.addValueEventListener(this);
        forty1to50.addValueEventListener(this);
        fiftyTo60.addValueEventListener(this);
        sixty1Plus.addValueEventListener(this);

    }

}
```

Comment: Post your stack trace

Answer (score 0):

You set null values ​​to the chart.

```
String stringElevenTo20 = "0" , stringOneTo10 = "0", stringTwenty1To30 = "0", stringThirty1To40 = "0", string41T050 = "0", string51T060 = "0", string61 = "0";
```

You can start by replacing barEntries first.

```
ArrayList<BarEntry> barEntries = new ArrayList<>();
barEntries.add(new BarEntry(0,Float.parseFloat(stringOneTo10)));
barEntries.add(new BarEntry(1, Float.parseFloat(stringElevenTo20)));
barEntries.add(new BarEntry(2, Float.parseFloat(stringTwenty1To30)));
barEntries.add(new BarEntry(3, Float.parseFloat(stringThirty1To40)));
barEntries.add(new BarEntry(4, Float.parseFloat(string41T050)));
barEntries.add(new BarEntry(5, Float.parseFloat(string51T060)));
barEntries.add(new BarEntry(6, Float.parseFloat(string61)));
```

Then you can create your own ValueFormatter.

```
public class TitleFormatter extends ValueFormatter {


public TitleFormatter() {

}

@Override
public String getFormattedValue(float value) {
    int valueInt = (int) value;
    switch (valueInt){
            case 0 : return "1-10";
            case 1 : return "11-20";
            case 2 : return "21-30";
            case 3 : return "31-40";
            case 4 : return "41-50";
            case 5 : return "51-60";
            case 6 : return "61+";
            default:  return "";
     }
}

}
```

Set the xAxis formatter for your chart. Then you can see the values ​​like "1-10, 11-20, ..." on the chart.

```
BarDataSet barDataSet=new BarDataSet(barEntries,"Data set 1");

TitleFormatter axisValueFormatter = new TitleFormatter();
XAxis xAxis = barChart.getXAxis();
xAxis.setValueFormatter(axisValueFormatter);
```

update Chart func.

```
private void updateChart(){
        if (barChart.getData() != null &&
                barChart.getData().getDataSetCount() > 0) {
            ArrayList<BarEntry> barEntries = new ArrayList<>();
            barEntries.add(new BarEntry(0,Float.parseFloat(stringOneTo10)));
            barEntries.add(new BarEntry(1, Float.parseFloat(stringElevenTo20)));
            barEntries.add(new BarEntry(2, Float.parseFloat(stringTwenty1To30)));
            barEntries.add(new BarEntry(3, Float.parseFloat(stringThirty1To40)));
            barEntries.add(new BarEntry(4, Float.parseFloat(string41T050)));
            barEntries.add(new BarEntry(5, Float.parseFloat(string51T060)));
            barEntries.add(new BarEntry(6, Float.parseFloat(string61)));

            BarDataSet set1 = (BarDataSet) barChart.getData().getDataSetByIndex(0);
            set1.setValues(barEntries);
            barChart.getData().notifyDataChanged();
            barChart.notifyDataSetChanged();
            barChart.invalidate();
        }

    }
```

call updateChart in valueListener:

```
 simpleArcLoader.stop();
 simpleArcLoader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
 linearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
 updateChart(); // like this
```

Comment: First thanks for your valuable answer to my question. But there is a bug in the getFormattedValue method of the TitleFormatter class. And is called no executable code found.
And `int value = (int) value;` Here `value` variable has been used twice. And `barEntries.add (new BarEntry (" 1-10 ", Float.parseFloat (stringOneTo10)));` here only accepts float value  the x axis. Thank you

Comment: I edited my answer. I copied and pasted it from your question..